# Get mouse position absolute to the whole screen (in fullscreen mode)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, fullscreen, mouselistener

using JavaScript I'm trying to get the mouse position, absolute to the screen instead of the Browser (in full-screen mode).

My Laptop is running 1920*1080 screen resolution, so in theory when moving the mouse to the bottom right corner X should be 1920 and Y should be 1080.

Unfortunately the closest I get when clicking into the bottom right corner during full-screen mode is: X=1535, Y=863

Code:

```js
function printMousePos(event) {
  document.body.textContent = "clientX: " + event.screenX + " - clientY: " + event.screenY;
}
document.addEventListener("click", printMousePos);
```

```css
html body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Watch out, you are missing " before clientX. Anyway, have you tried pageX and pageY?

Comment: Yes I tried that as well - same result :/

Comment: **Your laptop is running windows 125% scale** Settings-Display-Scale. Your code (minus typo) works fine - it gives me 0-1919 for x.  Changing scale to 125% (looks horrid) and gives me 1535 for max x.

Comment: Oh wow *facepalm* - that's it, thx a lot!